# includeIf not showing expected username and email

Tags: git, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu. Here's `~/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
        email = 123456+mypersonalusername@users.noreply.github.com
        name = doug

[includeIf "gitdir:~/Projects/Work/"]
        path = ~/.git-work
```

Here's `~/.git-work`

```
[user]
        email = doug@work.com
        name = doug-work
```

On the terminal if I cd into `~/Projects/Work/` and then check my username or email:

```
git config user.name
doug

git config user.email
123456+mypersonalusername@users.noreply.github.com
```

Since I'm in directory `~/Projects/Work` I expected my git username and password to be `doug-work` and `doug@work.com` but my personal Github username and email are showing instead.

How can I use includeIf so that if I'm in `~/Projects/Work` git uses my work github settings?

Comment: Are your sure `~/Projects/Work` is a repository (working tree)? `includeIf` only works in repositories under `~/Projects/Work` but not in a non-repo directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `/~Projects/Work` is not part of a Git repository. Therefore, `gitdir` is not defined and does not match `~/Projects/Work/`.

If you `cd` into a Git repository inside `~/Projects/Work/`, this should work.

Comment: OK thanks. But in that case, if I want to clone a repo into `/~Projects/Work` using my work username and email, then includeIf will not work then? E.g. I tried cloning a work repo into /~Projects/Work just now and then cd into it. But when I check my username and email from within the newly cloned repo it still shows as having my personal creds. I presume because I cloned with my personal creds? I'm confused?!

Comment: @DougFir If you clone over SSH, you can configure different hosts for the purpose of credential selection.

Comment: I know it's besides the main q now but could you give an example of that?

Comment: @DougFir After cloning a repo into `~/Projects/Work`, `git config` should return work credentials for this repo (and also does return them on my system). Are you maybe either using wrong capitalization (`projects/work` instead of `Projects/Work`) or  making some other typo?

I think @iBug is talking about something like [this](https://superuser.com/a/1276490)

Comment: @0stone0 Sorry, we crossposted

Comment: @DougFir: as I mentioned in my long answer to your other question: "You'll want to control the URL for when you run push and fetch, so that Git passes the desired fake host name to ssh". For instance, suppose you have fake host names `gh.work` and `gh.home`. When you run `git clone` in your `Work` directory, you'd use: `git clone ssh://gh.work/path/to/repo.git`. That way the URL ssh will see uses `gh.work` and thus uses your work authentication.

Comment: Got it working, issue was I was using a rsa key when I needed an ed key. Not even sure what the difference is but it's going now!

Answer (score 1):

@DougFir: you should have only settings with sshCommand in .gitconfig  and the same time to delete(it's necessary) any configs with domains github.com, gitlab.com, etc in ~/.ssh/config